# use macro in legendentry

Tags: pgfplots, expansion, legend

I am creating a number of plots using a `foreach` loop. I want each of the plots to have a legend entry that is dependent on the loop parameter. My first attempt was (full MWE at the bottom of the post)

```
\foreach \p in {0, .125, ..., 1}{
    \addplot {\p * x};
    \addlegendentry{\p}
}
```

This throws an error though. The I tried replacing `\addlegendentry{\p}` by `\expandafter\addlegendentry\p`. This works to some extend, except that only the first character of `\p` seems to end up in the legend. Is there  a way to get the full contents of `\p` into the legend? I'm not too familiar with `\expandafter` so I am suspecting the error can be found there.

MWE that demonstrates the problem with the truncated legend entries:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        legend pos=outer north east,
    ]
    \foreach \p in {0, .5, ..., 4} {
        \addplot {\p * x};
        \expandafter\addlegendentry\p
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP's proposed `\expandafter\addlegendentry\p` will just take the first character (the 1st token) of the once-expanded `\p` as the argument to `\addlegendentry`.  Thus, the expansion of `\p` needs to remain in a brace group, so that all the digits are considered the argument.  To achieve that...

The key is `\expandafter\addlegendentry\expandafter{\p}`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        legend pos=outer north east,
    ]
    \foreach \p in {0, .5, ..., 4} {
        \addplot {\p * x};
        \expandafter\addlegendentry\expandafter{\p}
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That was quick! Thanks a lot. I'll accept the answer when I'm able to. If you don't mind: what does the second `expandafter` do conceptually and why does it needs `\p` to be in a group?

Comment: @Octaviour  The 1st `\expandafter` expands the 2nd `\expandafter`, and the 2nd `\expandafter` gets you past the opening brace in order to expand the `\p`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I did not realize the `{` was actually considered the next character as I tend to think of it as a grouping character that only groups the argument. Obviously this is not the case when used in combination with `\expandafter` as you demonstrated.

Comment: @Octaviour It is a hard concept for new users. But before it gets into TeX's mouth, the left brace is just a token.  Only after it gets into the mouth does it become a group delimiter.